# How to update part of session value only CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have a session variable which is

```
  $info = $this->session->userdata('userInfo');
```

and it has a data of this

```
 [user] => stdClass Object
    (
        [student_id] => 201410679
        [firstname] => NEHEMIAH
        [midname] => ONGTANGCO
        [lastname] => BALUYUT
        [username] => nobaluyut
        [password] => nobaluyut
        [email] => adre@fit.edu.ph
        [student_department] => CE
        [image_path] => assets/img/profiles/profile.jpg
        [student_is_blocked] => 1
        [offering_id] => 1
    )

[logged_in] => 1
[identifier] => student
[active_enrollment] => 1
```

How do I update [user][student_is_blocked] without overwriting the whole session variable?

Comment: `print_r($this->session->userdata());die;` and post data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **'userInfo'** is the session variable and has an array and variables in it. Then

```
$info = $this->session->userdata('userInfo');
$info['user']->student_is_blocked= "Any Value";
$this->session->set_userdata('userInfo', $info);
```

Comment: think you need quotes around `user` in as the array key